# vscode ps or cmd terminal does not open current working directory and python extinction not run working directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[ps or cmd terminal does not open current working directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeCvW.jpg)

[How can I do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJJUf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to know where the file is, and then you can copy your route to cmd and by using cd you will be in the route, then you can use py filename.py. (You need to have py installed in path) Also, you can use ctr+shift+c on vscode to open the working directory in cmd.